Why does this .NET code fail to retrieve Subject Key Identifier from a certificate?
Given a development environment of C# and .NET Core 7 with a variable of type X509Certificate2 signingCertificate , why does this Subject Key Identifier extraction fail on some machines?
var issuerSubjectKey = signingCertificate.Extensions["Subject Key Identifier"].RawData; 
This worked on development and test machines but 'issuerSubjectKey' is returned as null on some customer machines.

It turns out that the customer's machines were set to a different language and culture.  The following code works on all machines:
var issuerSubjectKey = signingCertificate.Extensions.OfType<X509SubjectKeyIdentifierExtension>().Single().RawData;

.FirstOrDefault might be wiser, in case it doesn't exist
